# matplotlib.pyplot: how to include custom legends when plotting dataframes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am plotting two dataframes in the same chart: the USDEUR exchange rate and the 3-day moving average.

```
df.plot(ax=ax, linewidth=1)
rolling_mean.plot(ax=ax, linewidth=1)
```

Both dataframes are labelled "Value" so I would like to customize that:

[image]

I tried passing the `label` option but that didn't work, as it seems that this option is exclusive to [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html) and not to [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html). So I tried using axes instead, and passing each label:

```
ax.plot(df, linewidth=1, label='FRED/DEXUSEU')
ax.plot(rolling_mean, linewidth=1, label='3-day SMA')
```

However now the legend is not showing up at all unless I explicitly call `ax.legend()` afterwards.

Is it possible to plot the dataframes while passing custom labels without the need of an additional explicit call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When setting a label using `df.plot()` you have to specifiy the data which is being plotted:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Value':np.random.randn(10)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Value':np.random.randn(10)})

df.plot(label="Test",ax=ax1)
df2.plot(ax=ax1)

df.plot(y="Value", label="Test",ax=ax2)
df2.plot(y="Value", ax=ax2)

ax1.set_title("Reproduce problem")
ax2.set_title("Possible solution")

plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]

**Update**: It appears that there is a difference between plotting a dataframe, and plotting a series. When plotting a dataframe, the labels are taken from the column names. However, when specifying `y="Value"` you are then plotting a *series*, which then actually uses the `label` argument.

Comment: Pretty weird that explicitly indicating the column to be plotted triggers the legend, but it does work. I guess it will make sense the more I use these libraries.

Comment: @dabadaba I've updated my answer with a bit more of an explanation as to why this happens